# Is it possible to set up a X450e-24t to handle network routing and gateway?

Tags: cisco-catalyst

Good morning all!

Very very junior tech support here so forgive me if this is not possible.

I just started somewhere and they have a Cisco Catalyst 6509 running that they say; "Just handles network routing and Gateway".  They also have an unused Extreme Networks x450e-24t switch that they have asked if I can set it up to replace the Catalyst.

They use just 198.162.1.xxx for everything and do not have more then 75 devices getting online.

Can I use the x450e-24t to replace the Catalyst and if so; anywhere online with some directions?

The previous person threw away all the paperwork for everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes an X450e-24t is a L2/L3 switch.  It will support basic routing protocols with the base edge license, or you can get the Advanced Edge license that will support OSPF v2/v3, VRRP, and ESRP.

The problem though is it's been EOL'd https://esupport.extremenetworks.com/eservice_enu/docs/summit_x250_x450e_endofsale_0713.pdf so XOS 15.3 is the last firmware version for it.

If you are OK with EOL'd products, then yes it will work.

Here's a link to the Install Guide: http://extrcdn.extremenetworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/100286-00_Rev17_InstallGuide.pdf and more importantly the Concepts Guide: http://extrcdn.extremenetworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/EXOS_Concepts_Guide_15_3_2.pdf

That should get you started...

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  They call it a switch, but according to its white paper it is also a router, and so it can be a gateway; it also supports some routing protocols if you need to connect several networks though it doesn't sound like you do.